# Externally Shared InfoPath Form SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365, forms-services, licensing

Wondering if someone can help with a problem I am having please. I am currently using SharePoint Online with InfoPath 2013 to setup a form. I have shared an InfoPath form externally with a user. However when the user tries to access the form they see the following:
[image: InfoPath License Error]

The error states that I do not have a license to use InfoPath Forms Services. However according to Microsoft "[external users inherit the use rights of SharePoint Online customer who is inviting them to collaborate](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin/infopath-forms-services-in-sharepoint-online/777e5681-b946-4d4c-9280-dcff5db9feaa)"

The user who has shared the form has an Office 365 Enterprise E3 license however we continue to see the error.

[image: Office 365 Enterprise E3]

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Answer (score 5):

Right, you cannot share an InfoPath or PowerApp form with external users.

As an alternative, I could suggest you taking a look at our [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/). This solution is designed for creating responsive forms and publishing them to modern SharePoint pages. But also, it allows you to create a form and publish it anywhere, at any website publicly available.

Then, handle form submissions with [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com) and save data anywhere - to a SharePoint list, send by e-mail, convert into PDF and put to OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

The external users just inherit the permission to the items/sites but not the license which the inviter has.

External users do not have a license to your Office 365 subscription, they are limited to basic collaboration tasks.

More information refer to [Manage external sharing for your SharePoint Online environment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85?CorrelationId=8f0eeb9f-263f-48bd-8305-17568a16161c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102849864)